# Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>' VueJs

Tags: javascript, class, vue.js, webpack, babeljs

I'm working on a Vue project with Webpack and Babel and trying to export two Js classes from one single file with module.exports and include it inside a component with require like this:

**classes.js**

```
class classOne {
  constructor(){
  }
  f1() {}
  f2() {}
  ...
}
class classTwo {
  constructor(){
  }
  f1() {}
  f2() {}
  ...
}
module.exports = {
  classOne,
  classTwo
}
```

**script tag of component.vue**

```
const classes = require('@/path/to/classes.js');

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      var: undefined,
      foo: undefined,
    }
  }
  created() {
    this.var = new classes.classOne();
    this.foo = new classes.classTwo();
  }
}
```

But i get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
```

Comment: What Babel plugins are you using?